# Reference to a covering theorem by Ketonen

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I am reading a paper by Goldberg, and he uses a theorem by Ketonen, which is highlighted in red below:
[image]

Do you know where can I find the theorem and it's proof?

Link to the article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07299

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I didn't give a reference. The theorem first appeared in spirit in Ketonen's paper "[Strong compactness and other cardinal sins](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484372900186)," **Theorem 1.3**.

The precise result I needed is proved in [my thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.03293) as **Theorem 7.2.12**, which states that if $j : V \to M$ is an elementary embedding, $\lambda$ is a regular uncountable cardinal, and $\delta$ is an $M$-cardinal, then $\text{cf}^M(\sup j[\lambda])\leq \delta$ if and only if $j$ is "$(\lambda,\delta)$-tight," which just means $j[\lambda]$ is contained in a set in $M$ of $M$-cardinality at most $\delta$.
**Lemma 7.2.7** states that an *ultrapower embedding* $j : V\to M$ is $(\lambda,\delta)$-tight if and only if $M$ has the "$({\leq}\lambda,{\leq}\delta)$-cover property," which just means that every subset of $M$ of cardinality at most $\lambda$ is contained in an element of $M$ that has $M$-cardinality at most $\delta$.

Comment: Excuse me for further asking, but is not needed for $\lambda$ to be weakly inaccessible in theorem 2.3 in the paper?

Comment: No, just regular. I don't know why I wrote weakly inaccessible...